# React Immutability-helper - update many similar objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, store

I have state in Redux Store and I want to change all isPlaying to false. I do not have idea how I can do that in better way. Here is what I did so far.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isPlaying: true,
  allLangs: [
        {
          shortName: 'es',
          fullName: "spanish",
          order: 0,
          isPlaying: false
        }, {
          shortName: 'pt',
          fullName: "portuguese",
          order: 0,
          isPlaying: false
        },
        {
          shortName: 'gb',
          fullName: "english",
          order: 0,
          isPlaying: true
        }
      ]
  }

return update(state,
      {
        $merge: {isPlaying: false},
        allLangs: {
          [0]: {
            $merge: {isPlaying: false}
          },
          [1]: {
            $merge: {isPlaying: false}
          },
          [2]: {
            $merge: {isPlaying: false}
          }
        }
      });
```

So my question: Is it any way to do this in better way than call to all index separatly ?

Answer (score 0):

Given your current data structure, if you want to set every instance of `isPlaying` to false, then what you have is correct. Depending on your use case, here are some other suggestions:

#### Reset to default

Let's say that whenever you set `isPlaying` to false, the game is over and you are starting a new game. Then, the easiest thing to do might be to just set the state to `initialState` directly.

#### Change data structure

This is dependent on your use case, but my first instinct is that your data structure has duplication. Can you really be playing a game in English and Spanish at the same time? If not, consider doing something like this:
const allLangs = {
  es: {
    fullName: "spanish",
    order: 0,
  }
}

Then, in yours state, you would point to the active language:

```
const state = {
  isPlaying: false,
  activeLanguage: "es"
}
```

Refactoring in this way gives you one single source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take the 'allLangs' array in separate array variable lets say 'newAllLangs' and use map() to change the 'isPlaying' and in the last set this 'newAllLangs' to state. Something like this.

I am considering you are doing this manipulation in userAction.js. So lets say you got allLangs via mapStateToProps and sent this data to userAction.js by using mapDispatchToProps. In userAction.js you can manupulate allLangs and send them back to reducer. And reducer will update store based on what you send from userAction.

This was theoretical part If you want more exposure. You can make a fiddle and can share here.